# Store different numbers into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say you have a situation where you get 3 numbers from different sources, I wanna merge them together in 1 array and came up with this. Its almost do the trick but I can't combine the numbers into 1 array

```
$(n + " " + 'ul').each(function(){
    var arr = ( $(this).children('li').size());
    var test = (""+arr).split("");
    console.log(test)
});

//Outcome in console
"1"
"2" 
"3"

//Outcome in console what I need
"1, 2, 3"
```

Something about this line isn't right, I know the split doesn't work but I can't come up with something better to achieve the result.

```
var test = (""+arr).split("");
```

Comment: `.size()` doesn't return an array, it returns a number. I don't understand what you're doing with that.

Comment: Yes I know but it takes the UL and takes the amount of list items from 1 single UL

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the result as one single string (and not an array), I would use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the result:

```js
var n = "div";
var res = $(n + " " + 'ul').map(function(){
    return $(this).children('li').length; // size() is deprecated
}).get().join(", ");
alert(res); // "1, 2, 3"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should it be something like this?  You are creating a new array every loop through there:

```
var test = [];

$(n + " " + 'ul').each(function(){
    test.push($(this).children('li').size());    
});

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
    $(n + " " + 'ul').each(function(){
        var arr = ( $(this).children('li').size());
        var test = arr.toString();
    });
    console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [*Array join*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var arr = [];
$(n + " " + 'ul').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).children('li').size()));
});
var test = arr.join(", ");
console.log(test);
```

Comment: `arr` is not an array, you can't use `.join` on it.

Comment: @Barmar updated my answer. I thought of just idea last time.